# Copying the column index of csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a csv file which I parsed from an html document using python whose first line is as follows:

```
Subject,External,Internal,Total,Result,Software Engineering ,Systems Software ,Operating Systems ,Database Management Systems ,Computer Networks  I ,Formal Languages & Automata Theory ,Database Applications Laboratory ,Systems Software & Operating Systems Lab. ,Total Marks
```

I want to copy `External,Internal,Total,Result`after each of `Software Engineering ,Systems Software ,Operating Systems ,Database Management Systems ,Computer Networks  I ,Formal Languages & Automata Theory ,Database Applications Laboratory ,Systems Software & Operating Systems Lab`

meaning it should endup as

```
 Subject ,Software Engineering,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Systems Software,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Operating Systems,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Database Management Systems,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Computer Networks  I,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Formal Languages & Automata Theory,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Database Applications Laboratory,External,Internal,Total,Result ,Systems Software & Operating Systems Lab,External,Internal,Total,Result
```

This will form the first line of my csv file.
I have another piece of code that will fill up rest of csv file.

What would be an easy way to acheive this?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to achieve, I don't think it's not clear what you mean...

Comment: edited the question with the output I am trying to achieve

Comment: question is not clear. if u want to write it on first line of csv then do a list and try csvwriter.writerow([yourlist])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('headers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
   header_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   headers = header_reader[0]
#You now have the headers from the first line of the CSV
#Extract the headers you want to repeat
repeat_headers = headers[1:5]  #contains [External,Internal,Total,Result]

#Build new list
new_headers = [headers[0]] + repeat_headers   #Your first element is at position 0
for i in xrange(5, len(headers)):             #Your remaining elements start at position 5
   new_headers.append(headers[i])
   new_headers += repeat_headers
```